# I've installed tkcalendar correctly but it shows up as missing import

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, tkcalendar

I've imported `tkcalendar` correctly but it shows up as "missing import". Can someone help? I'm on Visual Studio and I can't find out but it won't import `tkcalendar` when it's already been installed.

Comment: How did you install it?  It's quite possible you have several versions of Python installed, and you didn't install in the right one.  Try in your VSC console `python -m pip install tkcalendar`.

Comment: Please check which python interpreter you have selected from the bottom-left of VSCode, and where you have installed the package through `pip show tkcalendar`.